# Responsive Web Design: Lateral Scaling Window With Responsive HTML Body

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport

Following hours of research online--I have yet to find a solution to responsive web design as it pertains to preserving the ratio of the window and html body.

Examples (Original, Stretched Leftward, and Stretched Laterally):

[image: Original]
[image: Desired Behavior: No Change] 
[image: Desired Behavior: Responsive]

I am looking for the HTML body to resize with the lateral increase or decrease of the window/browser (no change if ratio increases in only a single direction). Including viewport related meta tags has not worked thus far but this may be due to "conflicts" of the page styles i.e. a fixed body or min-height/width elements (may be wrong). How would one accomplish this desired outcome?

Comment: Please reorganise the question. Set the image links correctly. Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure css solution your best bet is using `padding-bottom`. Padding % is relative to the width. For example if you set the height of the element to zero and padding-bottom to 100% it will always be square. Just change the percentage to match the aspect ratio you require.